# What other rules should I use to allow PPTP outbound connection?

Tags: iptables, firewall, pptp

I already allowed outbound connection to TCP/UDP port number 1723, but PPTP connection still fail to establish,

If I allow all outbound connection, the tunnel will just go fine.